# Can swap get corrupted?

Tags: swap, freenas

We keep having swap problems when moving a *lot* of files or deleting them. The latest message is "out of swap space"

We rebooted. However, "out of swap space" now occurs during boot. Freenas just doesn't boot.

That shouldn't happen, right? We thought swap should be cleared when you reboot.

Could swap have become corrupted?

Comment: Where exactly did you see this error message? Was there anything else around it? What is the output of `swapinfo`?

Comment: No idea what the output of swapinfo is, the server currently doesn't finish booting. We increased the RAM of the server. It is now busy importing a ZPool, but that takes a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `/etc/fstab` to see if it mounted the swap partition. If you do not have it, it creates a mount point.

What you can do is to expand swap:

- Create a swap of about 3G

  ```
  # dd if=/dev/zero of=/opt/extension_swap bs=1k count=3156992
  ```
- Change the permissions to 600

  ```
  # chmod 600 /opt/extension_swap
  ```
- Convert it to type swap

  ```
  # mkswap /opt/extension_swap
  ```
- Activate the swap space

  ```
  # swapon /opt/extension_swap
  ```
- Edit the /etc/rc.local file and add the following line

  ```
  swapon /opt/extension_swap
  ```
- To view the size of type Swap

  ```
  # grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo
  ```

Comment: You can add swapfiles to fstab, too; there is no need to use rc.local for this.